# Errno 13 Permission Denied on mac

Tags: python, permission-denied, errno

I am simply testing how to call external .py files from one .py file.
I have 2 .py files, both in the same directory. Here is the code for the main one (runext.py suppose to call ext.py):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("/Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/ext.py")
```

ext.py is just `print("hey this actually worked")`

However, every time I run runext.py, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/runext.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.call("/Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/ext.py")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 557, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I don't know why it denies permission. This is on a school computer (I'm in a programming class) if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to call the file via subprocess rather than just importing it?

Comment: Does `ext.py` have execute access?  `chmod u+x ext.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the permissions to execute the file `/Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/ext.py`

You can add the permission `+x` by using chmod:

`chmod +x /Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/ext.py`

Or, you can use python explicitly:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("python /Users/training/PycharmProjects/MarcouFirstProject/ext.py")
```